# In ElGamal, how does knowing the secret number used for a signature reveal the signer's private key?

Tags: elgamal-signature

In ElGamal, how does knowing the secret number used for a signature reveal the signer's private key? How do two signatures using the same secret number reveal the signer's private key?
[Hint: p-1 is twice a prime. Even though not all numbers have inverses mod p-1, division
can still be performed if one is willing to accept two possible answers.
(We're neglecting the case where the divisor is (p-1)/2, since it is
extremely unlikely.)]

Comment: If this is homework, you might consider thinking about the hint that's in the question...

Comment: I'm very confused on how to do this question even with the hint

Comment: If you have two signatures with the same secret, what can you learn?  Hint: why don't you explicitly write out the expressions that created the $s$ values in the two signatures.

Comment: "how does knowing the secret number used for a signature reveal the signer's private key?" - write out the formula that generates $s$; what's known, what's unknown?